How to fix "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Function' in VueJS?
I have a Vue component that takes a function pointer to perform a delete-action.
<template>
  <q-card class="my-card" >
    <q-img :src="media.normal || media.original">
      <div class="absolute-bottom text-center">
        {{ media.title || 'No Title'}}
      </div>
    </q-img>

    <q-card-section>
      <div class="text-h6">{{ media.title}}</div>
    </q-card-section>

    <q-card-section class="q-pt-none">
      <q-btn @click="actionDelete(media.uuid)">Delete</q-btn>
    </q-card-section>
  </q-card>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { PropType, ref } from 'vue';
import { MediaItem } from 'src/data/mediaItem';

const props = defineProps({
  media: {
    type: Object as PropType<MediaItem>,
    required: true
  },
  actionDelete: {
    type: Function,
    required: true
  }
});
</script>

According to what I found in documentation and tutorials, I'm passing the function from my  parent component to the child component:
<MediaItemComponent :media="media" :actionDelete="actionDelete(media.uuid)" />

However. VueJs (or TypeScript?) is complaining about that:
ERROR(vue-tsc)  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Function'.

What am I doing wrong?

I haven't used Vue.js, but it sounds like this issue. Perhaps :actionDelete="() => actionDelete(media.uuid)" (but there may well be a more Vue.js-esque way to do that).

"According to what I found in documentation and tutorials" - you misinterpreted them, you can link them if you're interested in knowing the difference

Type error shows the mistake in code. :actionDelete="actionDelete(media.uuid)" results in actionDelete prop being the result of actionDelete call, which is undefined in this case, while the prop is expected to be a function. actionDelete isn't supposed to be called with the same argument twice.
It's rarely needed to pass a callback through a prop in Vue, this is handled with Vue events, which are easier to debug in devtools.
Should be in the parent:
<MediaItemComponent :media="media" @delete="actionDelete" />

In the child:
<q-btn @click="$emit('delete', media.uuid)">


Thank you so much! Can you also help me how to emit such events outside of a click-event? I wrote another question for that purpose here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78398303/how-to-emit-an-event-in-vuejs-3-outside-of-a-component

You're welcome. With script setup syntax it's useEmit, as the answer suggested
